# Reparenting wm and BadWindow errors

Tags: c++, x11, xcb

I'm writing a reparenting window manager in XCB and C++:http://ix.io/3yNo

At the moment it works pretty well, but occasionally when I close a window, all the windows of that application close because the process exits with a BadWindow. For example if I have a couple xfce4-terminal windows open, all managed by one process,and I close one, occasionally the application will close and I will get a `BadWindow (invalid window parameter)` error (in the app, not my wm). The very interesting thing is that this is not reproducible but kind of rare, probably a race condition between reporting the error and closing the window due to X11's asynchoronous nature.I have no clue where to begin debugging this, any tips?I kind of suspect it might be something in the Unmap O

Comment: Don't put anything important at a link and since this question contains zero code but refers to code, I'm assuming that's what's at the link. And it's pretty important. Links rot, and this renders a question that leans too heavily on a link "Not Useful". Plus there's a large number of folk here that won't touch a link to an unknown site with a ten foot mouse cable because we don't want to find out the hard way what's lurking at the other side. If you have too much code to post here, that's that [mre]s are for.

Comment: Well, that and [mre] describes a powerful debugging technique that, if followed, often brings a question to an end unasked fairly quickly.

Comment: I can't create a minimal reproducible example, really, because the issue isn't at all reproducible. I'll put the relevant parts of code in the question.

Comment: That probably won't do much good. If we can't reproduce, the odds of finding the error go way down. If you post only portions of the code, the odds get lower still. For example, if you don't know what the bug is, how can you be sure what is or is not relevant?

Comment: Yeah, the issue is X11's asynchronous nature so I can get an error right when it happens or 2 hours later. I need to figure out how to force the error to occur right then, pehraps by somehow synchronizing everything on the X server.

Comment: I feel your pain. Often the hardest thing to do is reliably reproduce so that you can trace the bug. Otherwise it's dumb luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link contains almost 500 lines of code. I am not going to try to fully understand that. Instead, I'll just randomly guess.

```
auto window_manager::handle_unmap_notify(xcb_unmap_notify_event_t *ev) -> void {
  if (unmap_ignore > 0) {
    unmap_ignore--;
    return;
  }
  client *cl = nullptr;
  size_t idx = 0;
  for (client &c : clients) {
    if (c.window == ev->window) {
      cl = &c;
      break;
    }
    idx++;
  }
  if (not cl)
    return;
  xcb_destroy_window(conn, cl->frame);
  clients.erase(clients.begin() + idx);
}
```

You are destroying windows that are not yours. When the owner of the window accesses it the next time, it will get a `BadWindow` error.

Instead, you should check a window's `WM_PROTOCOLS` property and check for `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`. If that is present, you are supposed to send a `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` message to the window. See ICCCM § 4.2.8.1: https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.2.8.1

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't think this is the issue as I do own `cl->frame`, as I create it. What I do not own is `ev->window`.

Comment: Perhaps however the issue here is that even when a client unmaps a window it expects the window to be present and ready for drawing. When I destroy cl->frame I also subsequently destroy ev->window because it is a child of the frame window. I will try switching to xcb_unmap_window.

Comment: Ah, yeah, destroying a window also destroys all child windows.